Pole at Infinity of a 1-loop scalar bubble diagram
In What is the $i\epsilon$ for the $S$-matrix, chapter 3, they discuss over the singularities of a 1-loop scalar bubble diagram (3.12),
$$\mathcal{I}_{\text{bub}} = \Gamma(2-D/2)\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\int^{1}_{0}{\frac{d\alpha}{(-\tilde{\mathcal{V}}-i\epsilon)^{2-D/2}}}\tag{3.17}$$
where $\tilde{\mathcal{V}}$ is a function (3.13) of Feynman parameters $\alpha$ and kinematical variable $s$. I have a question concerning the following paragraph above eq. (3.24):

We still need $D < 4$ for $\alpha_±$ to be poles in the first place, but now also $D > 2$ for the integrand of (3.17) to have
a pole at infinity, hence, this singularity only exists in $D = 3$.

The condition $D<4$ is because we focus on the singularity of the integral caused by kinematical variable $s$ but not the UV divergence, and also due to the presence of poles.
The condition of $D>2$ confused me, and it tells that the existence of pole at infinity which I don't think so.
As far as I'm concerned, the position of the pole has already be determined by eq. (3.20):
$$\alpha_± = \frac{s-m_1^2+m_2^2±i\sqrt{-\Delta}}{2s}.\tag{3.20}$$
In the case of $s = 0$, the position of the poles is at infinity, then, what is the condition $D>2$ stands for?

FWIW, the very next sentence in the quote reads: It corresponds to the
collinear divergence for external particles.

You have to think about it as having to deform your integration contour to avoid the roots $\alpha_\pm$. When you move along the real $s$ axis, the roots move as follows (the arrows indicate increasing $\text{Re}(s)$):

As you can see, they never intersect the integration contour if you just follow a straight line with $\text{Im}(s)=0$. Therefore, you don't actually need to deform the contour (which remember is $0\leq\alpha\leq1$) when you approach $s\to0$ and both roots go to infinity. This is what the authors mean when they say that the singularity is not on the physical sheet.
However, if you changed the sheet by e.g. going around the $s^*$ singularity once before approaching $s\to0$ (which, as explained in section 3.2, has a branch cut associated to it and therefore a discontinuity) the roots $\alpha_\pm$ would approach the contour from the opposite side, and you would have to deform it to avoid them. Since they shoot off to infinity, you would eventually have to integrate over a region of arbitrarily large $\alpha$. Nevertheless, when $D\leq2$, the integral doesn't actually diverge in the region $\alpha\to\infty$ (since the integrand goes as $\alpha^{D-4}$ with the projective choice $(\alpha,1-\alpha)$), so there is no singularity in the amplitude. Therefore, the only integer dimension that yields an actual divergence in the region $s=0$ is $D=3$.
